# Dynamic popupmenu not scrolling in some device

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am using popupmenu with adding item programmatically.  in some devices, scroll inside popup menu not working.. It works perfectly till android version 8, but not in android 9.

```
popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), tvQty);
    //Inflating the Popup using xml file
    popup.getMenuInflater()
            .inflate(R.menu.menu_qty, popup.getMenu());

    for(int i = 1; i <= qty; i++){
        popup.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE, ""+i);
    }
    popup.show();
```

my menu_qty.xml is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</menu>
```

attahing below image: here 1 and 2 is not showing, and scrolls till end without scrollable top..

[image]

Comment: which device (android 9) you face this problem. is it happened on emulator? I want to know it to able to reproduce then maybe can find the problem

Comment: in real device. i.e. one plus

Comment: my xioami phone (android 9) android huawei (android 8) still working fine (it able to scroll and the menu display full). maybe other people who have onplus can help you